# only allow certain ip range to asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

in my asp code i was using

```
<%
UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
If UserIPAddress = "" Then 
UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
end if


IF Left(UserIPAddress,11) = "111.111.111" or Left(UserIPAddress,10) = "444.444.44"  then
%>
```

how could i do something like this in asp.net(using vb.net)

Comment: An octet consists of only 8 bits. An IPv4 address is 32 bits, and is often shown as the decimal value of each octet delimited by periods. The maximum decimal value represented by a single octet is `127`, which would make your example of an IP address starting with `444` invalid.

Comment: that isnt my actual ip its just an example

Comment: You might consider using actual authentication instead of playing games with IP addresses in your code. The hackers will _love_ you for doing that.

Comment: well first the page checks the ip and then they need a user name and password to access the page. there really nothing important on the page its just me playing around

Comment: This is very brittle approach, what if users IP changes ala DHCP or they get a different machine?  Reading online HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be easily hijacked.

Comment: well this was the method i used. I would love to use/learn a better method if you explained or showed me

Comment: what is the objective you are trying to achieve by pre-checking IP address?

Comment: to keep the page as an intranet site for people only in a specific office to use

Comment: managing the ip range through the web server might be a better option for you then if it is a static set of ranges, then you do not need to worry about IP range in your pages, you just need to ensure users are authenticated.

Comment: so i could do this from the IIS

Comment: what steps would i need to take to do this

Comment: Try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324066

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim userIPAddress As String =  Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") 

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(userIPAddress) Then
    userIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End If

If userIPAddress.StartsWith("111.111.111") Or userIPAddress.StartsWith("444.444.44") Then
  ' Do  something
End If
```

So you'll notice the `Request` object still exists and in this case works the same.  Strings are now objects as well, so typically you wouldn't see any functions like `Left`.  `userIPAddress == ""` should still work, though I put in `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: im trying to do it in vb.net, but ill convert it and see if it works

Comment: Sorry, it was messed up before (half C#, half VB.NET).  I have updated my answer, but I'll warn you it's untested.

Comment: if i want it to load my page what would i put for do something

Comment: You could direct them away (`Server.Transfer`) if they do not match your criteria.